# Publish to web is not working after upgraded from VS2013 to VS 2015 and from MSSQL LocalDB 2012 to 2014

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I updated Visual Studio 2013 to 2015 and updated SQL Server (LocalDB) from version 2012 to 2014. Now when I want to publish my project to the web I get this error.

```
Web deployment task failed. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
```

I searched through the files in the project like `sln` and `csproj` files and set everything to the correct VS2015 (14.0) version.

The server where I publish is running SQL Server Web 2012, but I can't update that server just yet.

Can anyone help me? I don't know where to look to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: I just re-installed my whole computer because I can not find the problem. Re-installed Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 community edition and tried again. Same error, when there is no database in de project there are no problems, when I add a database to the project I get the same error as above.

Comment: I reinstalled Windows 10 again, this time with Visual Studio 2013 and everything is working again. I guess there is a little bug in VS2015.